# Using PyOpenGL, how do you apply instancing on an .obj file?

Tags: python, opengl, .obj

I am trying to apply instancing on a object (.obj) file by following the example on [Learn Opengl - Instancing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing).

**My question is actually twofold:**

1) How to apply instancing on .obj files? (I think I'm almost there)

2) As I understand, to use instancing it is necessary to store the .obj file in a vertex array buffer (VAO), and therefore need help setting the materials and textures for the .obj file. That is if my assumption is true? (For now I just assigned the object to a solid white colour.)

**What I have done so far:**

I use Pywavefront to load the .obj file but I'm not stuck on it if another obj loader is needed.

Setting locations of where to place the object:

```
        #Locations
        vertices = [[-33.64413, 0.0, 19.03057], [-33.64818, 0.0, 19.0219],
                        [-33.64921, 0.0, 19.011],[-33.64913, 0.0, 19.03027], [-33.69828, 0.0, 19.0219],
                        [-33.64991, 0.0, 19.021]]

        self.vertices = numpy.array(vertices, dtype='f')
```

Loading OBJ and collecting vertices and faces (indices):

```
        obj_file = pywavefront.Wavefront('OBJ_PINS/Mcdonalds.obj', collect_faces=True)
        obj_vertices = numpy.array(obj_file.vertices, dtype='f')
        faces_list = []
        for mesh in obj_file.mesh_list:
            for face in mesh.faces:
                faces_list.append(face)

        obj_ind = numpy.array(faces_list,  dtype=numpy.int32)
```

I then create a Vertex Array Object (VAO) with the necessary vertex buffer object (VBO):

```
  VAOs = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(VAOs)

        # Vertex Buffer Object
        VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vertices.nbytes, obj_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        # Element Buffer Object
        EBO = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ind.nbytes, obj_ind, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        # vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, obj_vertices.itemsize * 3, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
```

Transforming and storing the object for instancing:

```
      # instance locations
      amount = len(self.vertices)
      #List storing the same object in different places
      modelMatrices = []

      #Storring the objects in a list
      for i in range(0, amount):
          model_o = glm.mat4(1.0)
          model_o = glm.translate(model_o, glm.vec3(self.vertices[i][0], self.vertices[i][1], self.vertices[i][2]))
          model_o = glm.scale(model_o, glm.vec3(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001))
          modelMatrices.append(model_o)
```

The interesting part, instancing the object to different places:

```
    #Create VBO for instancing
    instanceVBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(modelMatrices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    #Bind each vertex attrib array of matrices (4 vectors in Matrix)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3)
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p(0))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4)
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p(glm.sizeof(glm.vec4)))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5)
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p((2 * glm.sizeof(glm.vec4))))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(6)
    glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p((3 * glm.sizeof(glm.vec4))))

    #Set instancing
    glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1)
    glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1)
    glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1)
    glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1)

    #End VAO    
    glBindVertexArray(0)
```

The shaders:

```
self.vertex_obj = """
                       # version 330
                       in layout(location = 0) vec3 aPos;
                       in layout (location = 3) mat4 instanceMatrix;

                       uniform mat4 model;
                       uniform mat4 view;
                       uniform mat4 projection;

                       void main()
                       {
                           gl_Position = projection * view * instanceMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
                       }
                       """
 self.fragment_obj = """
                       #version 330
                       out vec4 FragColor;

                       void main()
                       {                           
                               FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0);
                       }
                        """
```

When I draw the object in the drawing loop I only see one object and not 6:

```
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs)
    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, len(obj_ind)*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None, amount)
    glBindVertexArray(0)
```

**What I think is wrong:**

I need to call the whole list of matrices to be drawn in the  instanced glBufferData but don't know how to do that.

Should it change to something like:

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount * glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(modelMatrices[?]), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

## FULL CODE

```
    import numpy
    import glfw
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader
    import pyrr
    import glm
    from pyrr import  matrix44
    from math import sin, cos, radians
    from OBJ_Loader import*
    import pywavefront



    class threeD_viewer():
        def __init__(self):

            vertices = [[-33.64413, 0.0, 19.03057], [-33.64818, 0.0, 19.0219],
                            [-33.64921, 0.0, 19.011],[-33.64913, 0.0, 19.03027], [-33.69828, 0.0, 19.0219],
                            [-33.64991, 0.0, 19.021]]

            self.vertices = numpy.array(vertices, dtype='f')

            self.cam = Camera(self.vertices[0][0], self.vertices[0][2])
            self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = 1280, 720
            self.lastX, self.LastY = self.WIDTH / 2, self.HEIGHT / 2
            self.first_mouse = True
            self.forward, self.backward, self.right, self.left, self.up, self.down = False, False, False, False, False, False

            self.x_start, self.y_start = self.vertices[0][0], self.vertices[0][2]

            self.vertex_obj = """
                       # version 330
                       in layout(location = 0) vec3 aPos;
                       in layout (location = 3) mat4 instanceMatrix;

                       uniform mat4 model;
                       uniform mat4 view;
                       uniform mat4 projection;

                       void main()
                       {
                           gl_Position = projection * view * instanceMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
                       }
                       """
            self.fragment_obj = """
                       #version 330
                       out vec4 FragColor;

                       void main()
                       {                           
                               FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0);
                       }
                        """
            self.main()

        # the keyboard input callback
        def key_input_clb(self, window, key, scancode, action, mode):
            if key == glfw.KEY_ESCAPE and action == glfw.PRESS:
                glfw.set_window_should_close(window, True)
            if key == glfw.KEY_W and action == glfw.PRESS:
                self.forward = True
            elif key == glfw.KEY_W and action == glfw.RELEASE:
                self.forward = False
            if key == glfw.KEY_S and action == glfw.PRESS:
                self.backward = True
            elif key == glfw.KEY_S and action == glfw.RELEASE:
                self.backward = False
            if key == glfw.KEY_A and action == glfw.PRESS:
                self.left = True
            elif key == glfw.KEY_A and action == glfw.RELEASE:
                self.left = False
            if key == glfw.KEY_D and action == glfw.PRESS:
                self.right = True
            elif key == glfw.KEY_D and action == glfw.RELEASE:
                self.right = False
            if key == glfw.KEY_Q and action == glfw.PRESS:
                self.up = True
            elif key == glfw.KEY_Q and action == glfw.RELEASE:
                self.up = False
            if key == glfw.KEY_E and action == glfw.PRESS:
                self.down = True
            elif key == glfw.KEY_E and action == glfw.RELEASE:
                self.down = False

        def do_movement(self):
            if self.forward:
                self.cam.process_keyboard("FORWARD", 0.000008)
            if self.backward:
                self.cam.process_keyboard("BACKWARD", 0.000008)
            if self.right:
                self.cam.process_keyboard("RIGHT", 0.000008)
            if self.left:
                self.cam.process_keyboard("LEFT", 0.000008)
            if self.up:
                self.cam.process_keyboard("UP", 0.000008)
            if self.down:
                self.cam.process_keyboard("DOWN", 0.000008)

        def mmouse_look_clb(self, window, xpos, ypos):
            if self.first_mouse:
                self.lastX = xpos
                self.lastY = ypos
                self.first_mouse = False

            xoffset = xpos - self.lastX
            yoffset = self.lastY - ypos

            self.lastX = xpos
            self.lastY = ypos
            self.cam.process_mouse_movement(xoffset, yoffset)


        def window_resize(self, window, width, height):
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
            projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45, width / height,  0.0001, 100)
            proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(self.shader_obj, "projection")
            glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection)

        def main(self):

            # initializing glfw library
            if not glfw.init():
                raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")
            # creating the window
            window = glfw.create_window(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT, "My OpenGL window", None, None)
            # check if window was created
            if not window:
                glfw.terminate()
                raise Exception("glfw window can not be created!")


            # set window's position
            glfw.set_window_pos(window, 400, 200)
            # set the callback function for window resize
            glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, self.window_resize)
            glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(window, self.mmouse_look_clb)
            glfw.set_input_mode(window, glfw.CURSOR, glfw.CURSOR_DISABLED)
            glfw.set_key_callback(window, self.key_input_clb)
            # make the context current
            glfw.make_context_current(window)

            self.shader_obj = compileProgram(compileShader(self.vertex_obj, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                         compileShader(self.fragment_obj, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))


            obj_file = pywavefront.Wavefront('OBJ_PINS/Mcdonalds.obj', collect_faces=True)
            obj_vertices = numpy.array(obj_file.vertices, dtype='f')
            faces_list = []
            for mesh in obj_file.mesh_list:
                for face in mesh.faces:
                    faces_list.append(face)

            obj_ind = numpy.array(faces_list,  dtype=numpy.int32)


            VAOs = glGenVertexArrays(1)
            glBindVertexArray(VAOs)
            # Vertex Buffer Object
            VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vertices.nbytes, obj_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
            # Element Buffer Object
            EBO = glGenBuffers(1)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ind.nbytes, obj_ind, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
            # vertices
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, obj_vertices.itemsize * 3, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

            # instance locations
            amount = len(self.vertices)
            #List storing the same object in different places
            modelMatrices = []
            #Storring the objects in a list
            for i in range(0, amount):
                model_o = glm.mat4(1.0)
                model_o = glm.translate(model_o, glm.vec3(self.vertices[i][0], self.vertices[i][1], self.vertices[i][2]))
                model_o = glm.scale(model_o, glm.vec3(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001))
                modelMatrices.append(model_o)

            #Create VBO for instancing
            instanceVBO = glGenBuffers(1)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO)
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(modelMatrices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
            #Bind each vertex attrib array of matrices (4 vectors in Matrix)
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(3)
            glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p(0))
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(4)
            glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p(glm.sizeof(glm.vec4)))
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(5)
            glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p((2 * glm.sizeof(glm.vec4))))
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(6)
            glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p((3 * glm.sizeof(glm.vec4))))
            #Set instancing
            glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1)
            glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1)
            glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1)
            glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1)

            #End VAO
            glBindVertexArray(0)


            glClearColor(0, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
            glEnable(GL_BLEND)
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

            #projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45, self.WIDTH / self.HEIGHT, 0.0001, 1000)

            projection = glm.perspective(glm.radians(45.0), self.WIDTH / self.HEIGHT, 0.0001, 1000)

            glUseProgram(self.shader_obj)
            view_loc_obj = glGetUniformLocation(self.shader_obj, "view")
            proj_loc_obj = glGetUniformLocation(self.shader_obj, "projection")
            model_loc_obj = glGetUniformLocation(self.shader_obj, "model")
            glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc_obj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(projection))
            glUseProgram(0)

            # the main application loop
            while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
                glfw.poll_events()
                self.do_movement()

                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

                glUseProgram(self.shader_obj)
                view = self.cam.get_view_matrix()
                glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc_obj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(projection))
                glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc_obj, 1, GL_FALSE, view)

                glBindVertexArray(VAOs)
                glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, len(obj_ind)*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None, amount)
                glBindVertexArray(0)

                glUseProgram(0)


                glfw.swap_buffers(window)

            # terminate glfw, free up allocated resources
            glfw.terminate()


    class Camera:
        def __init__(self, xstart, ystart):
            self.camera_pos = glm.vec3(xstart+0.005, 0, ystart+0.01)
            #self.camera_pos = glm.vec3(0, 0, 0)
            print(xstart+0.005)
            print(ystart+0.01)

            self.camera_front = glm.vec3(0.0, 0.0, -200.0)
            self.camera_up = glm.vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            self.camera_right = glm.vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

            self.mouse_sensitivity = 0.25
            self.jaw = -90.0
            self.pitch = 0.0

        def get_view_matrix(self):
            return matrix44.create_look_at(self.camera_pos, self.camera_pos + self.camera_front, self.camera_up)

        def process_mouse_movement(self, xoffset, yoffset, constrain_pitch=True):
            xoffset *= self.mouse_sensitivity
            yoffset *= self.mouse_sensitivity

            self.jaw += xoffset
            self.pitch += yoffset

            if constrain_pitch:
                if self.pitch > 45:
                    self.pitch = 45
                if self.pitch < -45:
                    self.pitch = -45

            self.update_camera_vectors()

        def update_camera_vectors(self):
            front = glm.vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            front.x = cos(radians(self.jaw)) * cos(radians(self.pitch))
            front.y = sin(radians(self.pitch))
            front.z = sin(radians(self.jaw)) * cos(radians(self.pitch))

            self.camera_front = glm.normalize(front)
            self.camera_right = glm.normalize(glm.cross(self.camera_front, glm.vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)))
            #self.camera_up = glm.normalize(glm.cross(self.camera_right, self.camera_front))

        # Camera method for the WASD movement
        def process_keyboard(self, direction, velocity):
            if direction == "FORWARD":
                self.camera_pos += self.camera_front * velocity
            if direction == "BACKWARD":
                self.camera_pos -= self.camera_front * velocity
            if direction == "LEFT":
                self.camera_pos -= self.camera_right * velocity
            if direction == "RIGHT":
                self.camera_pos += self.camera_right * velocity
            if direction == "UP":
                self.camera_pos += self.camera_up * velocity
            if direction == "DOWN":
                self.camera_pos -= self.camera_up * velocity

    threeD_viewer()
```

## Update

Instancing works now. The solution was to store a list of the vectors rather than the glm.mat4 objects:

```
        # instance locations
        amount = len(self.vertices)
        #List storing the same object in different places
        modelMatrices = []
        #Storring the objects in a list
        for i in range(0, amount):
            mod_list = []
            model_o = glm.mat4(1.0)
            model_o = glm.translate(model_o, glm.vec3(self.vertices[i][0], self.vertices[i][1], self.vertices[i][2]))
            for i in range(4):
                for j in range(4):
                    mod_list.append(model_o[i][j])
            modelMatrices.append(mod_list)
        modelMatrices = numpy.array(modelMatrices, dtype ="f")
        print(modelMatrices.shape)

        #Create VBO for instancing
        instanceVBO = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO)


        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount* glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), modelMatrices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Comment: I took a quick glance and seem like you set it up mostly correct and transforming maybe the problem.  I'm wondering if it's your transformation that you're sending in with vertexAttribPointer, can you try with a single vertexAttribPointer with 16 floats instead of using 4 Attribs like you currently have?  So for every instance you just get a single attribute of 16 floats (mat4) in your shader.

Comment: @nooibius. I tried a few things but maybe I don't understand the comment fully. I tried changing the attribpointer glEnableVertexAttribArray(3)
                    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), ctypes.c_void_p(0)) and comment out the rest, but nothing worked. Should something change in the shader as well?

Comment: Nevermind, you're right.  I looked up the API for glEnableVertexAttribArray, and you can't do what I was thinking.  I'll see if I spot something else.

Comment: Here's a suggestion, try using the instance id in the shader and compute an offset and create the transformation there in the shader (disable sending in instance transforms).  See if you get multiple instances to show up.  Once you get that working, then we know it's the instance transform that we're sending in is not working.

Comment: @Noobius. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try and implement the offset method after a good nights rest, but I think that is a good place to start.

Comment: The problem may be that your geometry is indexed (GL_ELEMENT_BUFFER) and I'm not sure if glVertexAttribDivisor still works if you call glDrawElements_ instead of glDrawArrays_
I suggest testing with a non-indexed triangle.
If that is the case, I've used 1 dimensional Texture Buffer Objects indexed by gl_InstanceID to pass big arrays of numbers to a vertex shader

Comment: I got multiple instances to show up using the offset method. I had to set the vertices a bit farther away from each other as the object is very large without scaling but it showed multiple instances. So it must be the instance transform that is not correct. Another thing I noticed is that when I change  glm.value_ptr it shows the object at the model given. Example glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(modelMatrices[1]), GL_STATIC_DRAW) shows the object at the second location.

Comment: @Hugh. Thanks for the suggestion, I tried using the glDrawArraysInstanced call instead, without indices in the buffer, but it also did not work.

Comment: O.k. The solution to the first problem was to convert the glm.mat4 objects in my list to a "normal" list and convert it to a float numpy list. so modelMatrices is now a numpy list with shape (6,16) and glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount* glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), modelMatrices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

Comment: If anyone is interested, I created a new obj loader which handles instancing and textures. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239145/pyopengl-obj-loader-improvements